# Stripping away text and replcing <p> with /n with php

Tags: php, javascript

My output from another program is e.g.

```
<a href="blah@blah.com">blah@blah.com</a>
```

and

```
abc</p>
<p>xyz</p>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
```

I still need the newline if `<p></p>` appears, and I don't want the mailto link of the email as I am going to put them in textboxes.
Using php to replace, I could not get it done.

```
$afterClean = str_replace("<p>", "\n",$beforeClean);
```

What have I done wrong, and what is the easiest way to strip away all html codes (I can forgo everything between sharp arrows "<>" except  "p" as I need to replace with newline.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip-tags) will do this just fine.

Comment: You saved so much of my time. Thank you master!

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`$afterhtmlclean = strip_tags($beforeClean, '<p>')`;

it will remove all html except from `<p>`.

now you can use

`preg_replace(array('/(<p>)/','(<\/p>)'), array('','\n'), $afterhtmlclean )`;

it will remove your `<p>` tag with null and will add \n after your text to add new line in your text field